# Where was this photo of a bridge taken?

Tags: where-on-earth, beijing, lock-screens

[image]

Windows Spotlight showed me this picture.
But no way to get the place it was shot.

Comment: @pnuts This is not a puzzle in the sense that would be accepted there.

Answer (score 16):

It is one of the [Weilaikejicheng Road Bridges](http://english.visitbeijing.com.cn/discover/top/n215177947.html)

> There are two bridges on Weilaikejicheng Road, and this is one of them. The bridge also gained the name “Bird’s Nest Bridge” for its appearance.

It can be found [here on Google Maps](https://goo.gl/maps/jsjZK4GJXAJ2).

Also found it as [Rainbow Arch Bridge](http://epicwallpapers.com/places/roads/rainbow-arch-bridge-in-beijing.wallpaper) in Beijing, or [here](http://image.baidu.com/search/detail?ct=503316480&z=&tn=baiduimagedetail&ipn=d&word=%E6%9C%AA%E6%9D%A5%E7%A7%91%E6%8A%80%E5%9F%8E%E8%B7%AFqiao&step_word=&ie=utf-8&in=&cl=2&lm=-1&st=-1&cs=2773814124,707602238&os=213232509,1242666187&simid=3361764655,141796248&pn=25&rn=1&di=28194328811&ln=1978&fr=&fmq=1474135390207_R&fm=result&ic=0&s=undefined&se=&sme=&tab=0&width=&height=&face=undefined&is=&istype=2&ist=&jit=&bdtype=15&adpicid=0&pi=0&gsm=0&objurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.my0832.com%2Fattachments%2Fbbs%2F20140615%2F201461511582678522.jpg&rpstart=0&rpnum=0&adpicid=0&ctd=1474135453492%5E3_1465X947%251), [here](http://image.baidu.com/search/detail?ct=503316480&z=&tn=baiduimagedetail&ipn=d&word=%E6%9C%AA%E6%9D%A5%E7%A7%91%E6%8A%80%E5%9F%8E%E8%B7%AFqiao&step_word=&ie=utf-8&in=&cl=2&lm=-1&st=-1&cs=392527351,952356158&os=3299317194,245303751&simid=0,0&pn=12&rn=1&di=1325593731&ln=1978&fr=&fmq=1474135390207_R&fm=result&ic=0&s=undefined&se=&sme=&tab=0&width=&height=&face=undefined&is=&istype=2&ist=&jit=&bdtype=15&adpicid=0&pi=0&gsm=0&objurl=http%3A%2F%2Fimgs.soufun.com%2Fnews%2F2015_10%2F29%2Fesf%2F1446111723976_000.jpg&rpstart=0&rpnum=0&adpicid=0&ctd=1474135402380%5E3_1465X947%251) and [here on Baidu](http://image.baidu.com/search/detail?ct=503316480&z=undefined&tn=baiduimagedetail&ipn=d&word=%E6%9C%AA%E6%9D%A5%E7%A7%91%E6%8A%80%E5%9F%8E%E8%B7%AF&step_word=&ie=utf-8&in=&cl=2&lm=-1&st=undefined&cs=3438042050,1846468852&os=3115428136,1284484435&simid=0,0&pn=14&rn=1&di=246858147041&ln=1109&fr=&fmq=1474135261542_R&fm=&ic=undefined&s=undefined&se=&sme=&tab=0&width=&height=&face=undefined&is=&istype=0&ist=&jit=&bdtype=15&adpicid=0&pi=0&gsm=0&objurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bridgehead.com.cn%2Fdata%2Fattachment%2Fforum%2F201509%2F06%2F224835x7a9z20hahhsawt3.jpg&rpstart=0&rpnum=0&adpicid=0&ctd=1474135274198%5E3_1465X947%251). The bridge seems new enough that [Baidu Maps](http://map.baidu.com/#panoid=01002200001308041256402555Q&panotype=street&heading=247.58&pitch=9.62&l=18&tn=B_NORMAL_MAP&sc=0&newmap=1&shareurl=1&pid=01002200001308041256402555Q) does not have a streetview of it yet.

Comment: You're right, you win !
There are not so many photos of this bridge on the web.
Here is one of these http://english.visitbeijing.com.cn/discover/top/n215177947.html

Comment: @AlessandroLandi, if you are happy with an answer, please accept it, (there is a little tick next to the answer you can click on to do so.)

Comment: Pyrotechnic display of searching skills, great answer!